# Which is root, intermediate or issued ssl certificate?

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate, keystore, godaddy-api

I requested a certificate from godaddy and I received 3 files.

```
a5daacfb38e03863.crt
gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
gdig2.crt.pem
```

I am about to install it in my tomcat 8.

But I am not sure where is the root, intermediate or issued SSL cert.

I checked the gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt, It has 3 certificates:

And I noticed that the first one is thesame as gdig2.crt.pem (first one shown below)

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: Use `openssl x509 -text -in` to see the content of each. I guess `a5daacfb38e03863.crt` is the end (client) certificate, while `gdig2.crt.pem` is the root certificate, and the middle one the intermediary or the full chain with root too. It is the full chain in fact based on your observations at the end.

Comment: [GoDaddy docs](https://www.godaddy.com/help/tomcat-generate-csrs-and-install-certificates-5239) might help.